# Split comma-separated entries to new rows (No VBA)

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2007, worksheet-function, unpivot

I currently have this data in a sheet:

```
Col A   Col B
105     399, 400
207     405,406,407
```

and want to split the comma-separated entries in the second column and insert them in new rows as below:

```
Col A   Col B
105     399
        400
207     405
        406
        407
```

without resorting to VBA.

Is this possible?

Comment: This is a requirements description with no effort/attempt/research shown.

Answer (score 0):

Split ColB with Text to Columns and Space and Comma as delimiters. Follow the process described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20541905/convert-matrix-to-3-column-table-reverse-pivot-unpivot-flatten-normal/20543651#20543651) then delete ColumnB, select `(Blanks)` in Value column and delete those rows. If you do not want the ColA values to repeat, in a new column Row2 insert:

```
=IF(A1<>A2,A2,"")
```

and copy down to suit. Select that column, Copy, Paste Special, Values over the top then copy again and paste into the Table. If you don't want Table format, right click within it and Table, Convert to Range.